# How to calculate wifi connected duration...?

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which i want to calculate the wifi connected duration...for this i am using the broadcast receiver to get the connected and disconnected status..........but i am not getting the result..

```
ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo info = conman.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            State state = info.getState();          

            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();           

            if(state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            {   

                int hour,minute,sec;
                Time now  = new Time();
                now.setToNow();

                hour = now.hour;
                minute = now.minute;
                sec = now.second;

                String conTime = hour+":"+minute+":"+sec;

                edit.putString("conTime", conTime);
                edit.commit();
                connTime.setText(conTime);
            }
            else if(state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED )
            {   
                int hourd,mind,secd;

                Time nowd = new Time();
                nowd.setToNow();

                hourd = nowd.hour;
                mind = nowd.minute;
                secd = nowd.second;

                String dconTime = hourd+":"+mind+":"+secd;
                edit.putString("dconTime", dconTime);
                edit.commit();
                disconnTime.setText(dconTime);

            }
```

for this i have used two text view in my app first to show the time when wifi is connected...and the second to display the disconnected time....but each time when the app start its shows the diconnected time ...but i don't want that i want the two textview to remain blank.... untill i turn wifi on/off...how can i do that....

Comment: Is there any reason why you're putting the start and end time in preferences? I would imagine you're only interested in the information from the time the application starts.

Comment: I am using preferences to store the time to calculate after wifi is disconnected....and i have an button in my app which i am using to turn wifi on and off..and the text views to show it every time..

Comment: Is this the only code that calls `setText()` on your text views?

Comment: yes,this the only code ...ihave another text view to display the calculated time after getting connected and disconnected time..............

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in this way by retrieving System time on connected and when its disconnect you can get that time instance, by subtracting it will give you totalTime, which can be used to get Calender instance and from it you can easily get Hour/Minute/Seconds.

```
if(state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
    long connectedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(connectedTime);
    yourTextView.setText(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " hours, "+ cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " minutes, "+ cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " seconds ");

}
else if(state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ){
    long disconnectedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(disconnectedTime);
    yourTextView.setText(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " hours, "+ cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " minutes, "+ cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " seconds ");
}
```

//  long totalDuration = disconnectedTime - connectedTime;

Comment: thank's for your reply....but using the above i always get disconneted time when the app start....because its getting the disconnected state when app starts, but i don't want the disconneted time when the app start.....how can i do that..?

Comment: It will shows you upTime of wifi which you can replace with Time (if you have such requirement then) to show current time, you just need to set two different objects so it won't cause collision.

Comment: does your wifi on? while you start your application?

Comment: No...i start the app turning wifi off but still it shows the disconnected time...

Comment: if you start your app with wifi turned off then its obvious that it will shows you disconnected time, the code it self went to "else if" statement because ,it gets wifi disconnected event from android system.

Comment: there is lots of way but problem is not in the way you retrieve time, problem become the way you want your code to behave!, please reconsider wifi events and broadcasts because i think it becoming more Off-topic discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73218/discussion-between-noob-coder-and-apar-amin).